# How to retrieve output from error.log within container?

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm trying to debug networking issue with Nginx container. It throws status code 502.

I know the log is located in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`. When I open interactive shell:

`docker exec -it nginx_container /bin/sh` and quickly `cd` into the location I'm
unable to open it with `nano`, `vi` or get the content with `cat`.

How can I retrieve content of the error log ?

config.file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    proxy_pass        http://users:5000;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_connect_timeout 120;
    proxy_send_timeout 120;
    proxy_read_timeout 120;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    client_max_body_size 1500M;
    keepalive_timeout 120;
  }
}
```

in my flask config I included `app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024` to avoid code 413.

I'm sending files <= 10MB in size to that route.

Comment: If you haven't modified the container configuration at all, it will be in the `docker logs` output.

Comment: @DavidMaze  I know about `docker logs` command, however it doesn't give me the very much needed detail. Status code 502 is too vague. Dozen things can cause it. Error log narrows it down considerably.

Comment: More specifically, in the standard nginx setup, [`/var/log/nginx/error.log` is a symlink to `/dev/stderr`](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/c411fdefd6655144f6cdab425026a8a427adc273/mainline/debian/Dockerfile#L102), so anything that would go to the error log goes to the server's stdout and thence to `docker logs`.  There isn't by default a separate log file.

Comment: @DavidMaze  `docker logs nginx` gives me `sendfile() failed (32: Broken pipe) while sending request to upstream` which again isn't very helpful. I'll include my config file.

Comment: @DavidMaze I've added more details.